# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split' while running larger dataset

Tags: python-3.x

i get this error when i run the code on larger dataset. it works fine with smaller dataset.

running the code on 1.4m questions dataset. and using the split function gives error.

```
def build_vocab(sentences, verbose=True):

    vocab = {}

    for sentence in tqdm(sentences):
        for word in sentence:
            try:
                vocab[word] += 1
            except KeyError:
                vocab[word] = 1

    return vocab    
sentences = train_df["question_text"].progress_apply(lambda x: x.split()).values
vocab = build_vocab(sentences)
```

> ~\Documents\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in
>   apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    3589
>   else:    3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
>   -> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    3592     3593         if len(mapped) and
>   isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> ~\Documents\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tqdm_tqdm.py in
>   wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>       671                     # take a fast or slow code path; so stop when t.total==t.n
>       672                     t.update(n=1 if not t.total or t.n < t.total else 0)
>   --> 673                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       674 
>       675                 # Apply the provided function (in **kwargs)
>
> in (x)
>        11 
>        12     return vocab
>   ---> 13 sentences = train_df["question_text"].progress_apply(lambda x: x.split()).values
>        14 vocab = build_vocab(sentences)
>
> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
>
> 30%|██▉       | 310851/1048575 [00:20<00:08, 86263.52it/s]  30%|██▉
>   | 310851/1048575 [00:20<00:04, 163203.19it/s]

Answer (score 0):

Convert the x into string then use split. Your dataset might have float value somewhere, that's why the exception.

Comment: df_new = df[df['qid'].notnull()] using this to eliminate nan value but not working

Comment: To drop all the rows containing nan values use df.dropna().